# How to resolve this DeclratationError in the following Solidity Code?

Tags: solidity, remix

Why is the line '''SecretVault _secretVault = SecretVault(secretVault);''' in the following code throwing compilation error "DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier....."

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/**
 * @title SixthContract
 * @dev Exploring inheritance, factories and interaction with other smart contracts.
 */

contract Ownable {

    address owner;

    constructor()  public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }


    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Must be Owner.");
        _;
    }
}

contract SecretVault {
    string secret;

    constructor(string memory _secret) public {
        secret = _secret;
    }

    function getSecret() public view returns(string memory) {
        return secret;
    }
}

contract SixthContract is Ownable {

    string secret;

    constructor (string memory _secret) public {
        SecretVault _secretVault = new SecretVault(_secret);
        secret = _secret;
        super;
    }

    function getSecret() public view onlyOwner returns(string memory) {
        SecretVault _secretVault = SecretVault(secretVault);
        return _secretVault.getSecret();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Probably, it should be written there: 
SecretVault _secretVault = SecretVault(secret);
but there will be further conversion errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in SixthContract contract

1. Usage of `super` in the constructor doesn't make much sense

   ```
    super;
   ```
2. `getSecret` uses a variable `secretVault` that's not defined anywhere.

   ```
    SecretVault _secretVault = SecretVault(secretVault);
   ```

   I'd guess you want that variable at the contract level and initialize it in the constructor so it can be used from the view function.

```
contract SixthContract is Ownable {

    string secret;
    SecretVault secretVault;

    constructor (string memory _secret) public {
        secretVault = new SecretVault(_secret);
        secret = _secret;
    }

    function getSecret() public view onlyOwner returns(string memory) {
        return secretVault.getSecret();
    }
    
}
```